# Mapping column values to enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a Grid (using jquery grid) where I am showing data from my database table as:

```
Id    Fname    Lname    Role    Active
 1     John      Doe      0          1
 2     Henry    Beek      1          1
```

The role above maps to another reference table in my database as:

```
Id    Role
 0    None
 1    Admin
```

Now instead of showing 0,1 as the roles. I want to show None,Admin in my grid.
I created an enum for the same as:

```
  public enum Role 
    {
        None = 0,
        Admin = 1
    }
```

But I am not sure how can I map/manipulate the column data with this.

I can also attach a row formatter to each row something like below:

```
 function formatImage(cellValue, options, rowObject)
 {

 }
```

But here I have to check for each cellvalue then change it to none/admin. I have quite few columns for which I want to change the value as they are referenced from different table so using this method might not be appropriate.

Is there a better approach to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe do the mapping in the sql: [Mapping values in SQL select?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38567366)

Comment: this would be like to many case or if/else. Any better way to do that,

Comment: Anyone for inputs?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? It is good idea to show us the javascript code.  I suggest you to read the docs for [formatter 'select'](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#formatter-select) in case you use Guriddo jqGrid

Comment: I am using free grid. As I told I can do this via the grid, But wanted to see if there is an option or way from code, ie c# using some mapping etc